# Does the Google App Script API have the ability to obtain the user's current scroll-top location in a document?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The API has the ability to tell my script what the cursor position and what current document is active, but does it have the ability to tell the script what page the user is on or where the scroll-top in the document is (some way to tell how far the user has scrolled)?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. It can get element.isAtEndOfFile, it can get Cursor.getPosition, and it can get Bookmark.Position. But, because monitors are not one size, it cannot see how much is in your window/ how much you have scrolled.

However, if you would like that feature, GAS is an evolving platform and you can at a request at: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list